# ¿como compilar satisfactiramente un apk usando visual studio y ionic cordova?

Tags: android

estoy compilando mi app pero me sale este error al hacer click en release

no me deja compilar el apk de android

estoy usando visualstudio 2015 + cordova 6 + ionic 3 le doy release a dispositivo y me manda el siguiente error

```
MSBUILD : cordova-build error : TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null


1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
1>  TypeError Cannot read property '1' of null
========== Compilar: 0 correctos, 1 incorrectos, 0 actualizados, 0 omitidos ==========
========== Implementar: 0 correctos, 0 incorrectos, 0 omitidos ==========
```

Comment: no te compila por un error de código, en algún sitio estas intentando llamar a un objeto/array a la propiedad o posición "1". Puede ser que no tengas el objeto o array inicializado

Comment: Mira a ver si el config.xml está bien implementado y todos los campos activos están rellenos de forma adecuada.

Comment: Mira a ver si haces alguna comparación con 1 y te lo coge como variable en vez de valor

Comment: este es el detalle del error completo

El mapa de origen 'angular-aria.min.js.map' para el archivo 'www\lib\angular-material\angular-aria.min.js' no se pudo leer desde la ubicación especificada debido al error 'Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'TypeScriptSourceMapReader.SourceMapReadFailedException'.'.El mapa de origen 'angular-messages.min.js.map' para el archivo www\lib\angular-material\angular-messages.min.js' no se pudo leer desde la ubicación especificada debido al error 'Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'TypeScriptSourceMapReader.SourceMapReadFailedException'.'.

Comment: el error me sale para compilar otros proyectos donde no  tengo esos errores .. podria ser algo del sdk o del visual?